# How can I get my string variable to be in the same context as my @Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to send a string to my controller and cannot get the BeginForm to see the string.  I create lists using a loop then at the bottom of the loop I  create a string from the list then assign then attempt to send the string to the controller via the @Html.BeginForm but I get a the error message: “The name 'TheDateList' does not exist in the current context”

If I put the code at the top of the begin form, the string won’t be created so I put it after the loop at the bottom of the page somewhere. How can I get my string variable in the context of my BeginForm()?

Thanks for any help!!

```
      List<String> listOfSelectedTimes = new List<string>();  


      }

  @using (Html.BeginForm(new { someParam = TheDateList }))
   {

  foreach (var course in courses.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
  {




            String selectedDates = listofdates.ElementAt(course.Index);

            selecteddates = selectedDates;
            listOfSelectedDates.Add(selecteddates);




 }



  @ {          
 string thedatelist = string.Join(",", listOfSelectedTimes.ToArray());


      String TheDateList = thedatelist;


    }
```

Comment: If you want a variable to get posted in form, you need to make sure it is the value of an <input> (or select) in your html. In your case you can add `@Html.Hidden("TheDateList",TheDateList)` after you generated the String. Also just to remind, it is not suggested to do all the logic part in view. The cshtml files are real time compiled, you should make sure the logic part are finished in controller and only rendering-needed variables included in model and passed into view

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. It works fine.. I do try to avoid doing logics in the view but unfortunately my poor design at the beginning resulted in me creating loops of timepickers in the view then getting and setting data to and from them.. Beginner's stuff.